# Why does webpack include a module in my first entry as well as my page bundle

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-router

It seems like I'm having some sort of configuration issue with webpack and my react-router app.  I'm trying to break up the bundle by pages, but I'm using react-router and I have a single "main" which does a router.run to route the app paths.  It looks like when webpack runs that main file it will recursively write all the modules from main to the resulting bundle.

Here's a clonable repo which demonstrates the behavior

```
git clone https://github.com/adjavaherian/webpack-react-router
cd webpack-react-router
npm install
webpack
```

This will create a dist directory and you can check that the module is included twice using grep

```
$ grep -R zzz dist
dist/main.bundle.js:                'zzzzzz'
dist/mobileAppsPage.bundle.js:              'zzzzzz'
```

I'm expecting that because I'm using multiple webpack entries, only the mobileAppsPage.bundle.js should have the "zzzzzz" because that's the only place where the React TestClass.jsx is included.

Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?

https://github.com/adjavaherian/webpack-react-router

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't dug deep into Webpacks bundle splitting, but both your `main.js` and your `MobileAppsPage.jsx` has `TestClass.jsx` in it's direct dependency graph.

Since `main.js` requires `AppRoutes.jsx` which requires `MobileAppsPage.jsx`, both `main.js` and `MobileAppsPage.jsx` depend on `TestClass.jsx`. So there's not much to win in splitting those two.

What you probably want to do is to not require your route components at startup, but instead wait for the route to get hit and then load that bundle  asynchronously using `require.ensure` (http://webpack.github.io/docs/code-splitting.html).

Something like this (haven't tested it):

```
var MobileAppsPage = null;

var MobileAppsPageLoader = React.createClass({
  componentDidMount() {
    require.ensure(['./pages/MobileAppsPage'], () => {
      MobileAppsPage = require('./pages/MobileAppsPage');
      this.forceUpdate();
    });
  },
  render() {
    if (MobileAppsPage) {
      return <MobileAppsPage {...this.props} />;
    } else {
      return <div className="spinner" />;
    }
  }
});

var AppRoutes = (
  <Route path='/' handler={AppTemplate}>
    <Route name="FrontPage" path='/' handler={FrontPage}/>
    <Route name="MobileAppsPage" path="mobile-apps" handler={MobileAppsPageLoader}/>
  </Route>
);
```

You might also want to look at the example on code splitting in Webpack to split out modules from `node_modules` into a separate bundle (http://webpack.github.io/docs/code-splitting.html#split-app-and-vendor-code), since all your bundles will probably depend on React.

Comment: This works!  A few tweaks, in the repo, but you got the gist of it.  Thanks so much.